# Modify YAML file with PHP Symfony script

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

I  want to modify YAML file by using method which accepts two parameters: path to YAML file and array with proper values that also shows position in YAML file.

Example:

**input.yml**

```
config:
    parameter1: 
          key: val 
    parameter2: 
          boolean: true
```

**Array**

```
array(
  array(‘config.parameter1.subparameter’ => 1234),
  array(‘config.parameter3’ => ‘some_value’), 
);
```

**output.yml**

```
config:
    parameter1: 
          key: val
          subparameter: 1234
    parameter2: 
          boolean: true
    parameter3: 'some_value'
```

When I try to dump my array as YAML file, it should looks like this:

```
config:
    parameter1: 
          subparameter: 1234
```

But it looks like this:

```
config.parameter1.subparameter : 1234
```

Do you have any idea on how to convert key from my array to pair of keys and values to display it proper as YAML file? I tried to use `explode`, but I don't know how to attribute divided strings to key => value pairs. I'd be grateful for any kind of help.

**Full code:**

```
<?php

require 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vendor\autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;

class yamlParser {

    public $yamlParseArray = [];

    public function parser($filepath, $array) 
    {
        $yamlParseArray = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents($filepath));
        for($i = 0; $i<count($array); $i++)
        {
            foreach($array[$i] as $key => $value) 
            {  
                $divide = explode('.', $key);
                print_r($divide);
                for ($x = 0; $x < count($divide); $x++)
                {
                    $s = $divide[$x];
                    echo "s: ".$s."\n";
                    $helper = str_replace(substr($s,0),"['".substr($s,0),$s).substr($key,-1,0)."']";
                    echo "helper: ".$helper."\n";
                }
            }      
        }


        $yamlParseArray = array_merge($yamlParseArray,$array);
        $yaml1 = Yaml::dump($yamlParseArray, 4);
        file_put_contents('C:\xampp\htdocs\YAML_Parser\output.yml', $yaml1);
    }

}


$yamlParser = new yamlParser();

$filepath = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\YAML_Parser\input.yml';

$array = array(
    array('config.parameter1.subparameter' => 1234),
    array('config.parameter3' => 'some_value'),
);

$yamlParser->parser($filepath, $array);

?>
```

Comment: Show the code used to do that process. Thank you.

Comment: @DonCallisto - 
 
Here: paste.ofcode.org/yQ4eVZbHeLrf65cUzKhVJJ). Thanks for your engage. I'm pretty new in PHP, so sorry if code is bad

Comment: @Kamil Please edit your code into your question, so that your question isn't relying on third-party pages

Comment: @KhorneHoly I edited my question and added full code.